# Could Toxodon, Macrauchenia, and Megatherium be Domesticated, and if so, What Would Their Uses be?

Tags: fauna, ecology, domestication, prehistoric-times, livestock

In my book series, there is this huge flat savannah in the tropical north of my continent (it's in the southern hemisphere), very similar to the Brazilian cerrado in terms of plant life and animal life, but here much of the South American megafauna never went extinct. If this area were to be settled and cultivated by humans (who already had access to domesticated cattle, goats, and zebras (in lieu of horses)), could they domesticate some of these strange behemoths (notably [Toxodon Platensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxodon), [Macrauchenia Patachonica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macrauchenia), and [Megatherium Americanum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megatherium)), and if so what would they use them for?

[image: Toxodon (Ignore the fact it's getting mauled to death by sabertooths in this picture)]
Toxodon (Ignore the fact it's getting mauled to death by saberteeth in this picture)

[image: Macrauchenia]
Macrauchenia

[image: Megatherium]
Megatherium

Comment: VTC:Needs more Focus. That's three quesitons. You get one. I know the seem related, but the value of a horse vs. the value of a cow vs. the value of a cat are very different. It would also help of you brought a basic description of each creature into the question rather than relying on the link. I love the link, don't get me wrong, I just don't trust them.

Comment: The Macrauchenia image is outdated.

Comment: I am a bit baffled by the 'access to domesticated zebras' - to my knowledge those animals have never been successfully domesticated - and if you just domesticated them by fiat, why the interest in the domesticability of animals no one has ever seen? Zebras are very well known, and still their undomesticability is somewhat of a mystery (i.e. there are attemps at rationalizing it, but if you then look at domesticated horses and their wild forebears, you see that none of the arguments really holds water)

Comment: Generally, in order to be domesticated, a creature must be a herd/pack animal, and the human has to become the pack leader.  So do we know whether those megafauna were herd animals?  Size isn't really an issue, since humans manage to tame elephants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main uses of any animal are (a) beast of burden (b) riding and (c) source of meat, milk and wool.

All of your megafauna produce milk and meat and labour.  Will your settlers want to spend time and effort taming the megafauna  when they already have goats and cows that are much smaller and already domesticated?

A Toxodon is three times as strong as a cow yes. But it eats three times as much and is more than three times harder to control. With three cows you can have one person lead each cow and their herd instinct will make them follow each other. You also need stronger fences and ropes and doorways in case you plan on taking the animals inside during the winter.

The question for mounts is more interesting. Cattle do not make good mounts. Goats are too small. Zebras are famously bad-tempered and cannot be ridden. (Though perhaps they are physically suited to riding if the attitude could be bred out of them.) They have been used to pull a carriage at least once:

[image]

Are the megafauna physically suitable for riding? It is worth asking separately. I imagine there is a way to tell by looking at the skeleton and tell. I will go out on a limb and say Megatherium is a big no-no for riding. It is simply too different from a horse.

If they are physically suitable, it might be easier to breed a Macrauchenia to be smaller and calmer than breed a Zebra to be bigger and calmer. Perhaps  they would raise zebras for many generations to eat and pull carts, selecting the most docile ones to breed, and only then start trying to ride them.

The good thing is the megafauna are extinct. No one knows what their temperament was, and that means you get to decide how skittish and or aggressive they are. If you want rideable Macrauchenia I suggest you claim their large size makes them more calm than the zebras and so easier to domesticate.

There is something to be said for keeping zebras as an early warning system to fight off predators. [Though maybe you just need some donkeys for that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dA0IJFYfJl0)

Comment: "Perhaps they would raise zebras for many generations to eat and pull carts"  Why would you breed a zebra to eat a cart?  I mean, I guess it is a way to get rid of carts you don't need. but it seems like an unnecessarily complex solution to that problem.  :D

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile Herbivores can eat anything with cellulose. Carts are mostly cellulose. Duh!.

Comment: About the photo *"Not only were they real zebra, but he wasn't allowed to drive them on the public streets/carriageways except very early in the morning before any other equipages were out and about. Reason being: the zebra would frighten other horses. While quite the novelty, their appearance was nontheless "spook worthy" to the horse population of that day and age. Rothschild was said to have commented that driving a team of zebra was similar to driving donkeys (short, stubby little strides)"* https://twonerdyhistorygirls.blogspot.com/2012/07/lord-rothschilds-zebras.html

Comment: @Goodies Is that the same Rothschild from Rothschild's giraffe?

Comment: Hi @Daron yes, same Walter.. read the source link and this one https://storyteller.travel/rothschilds-giraffe/ Walter Rothshild had a museum-size animal collection in the 1890's.. he said it was a common misconception zebra's could not be tamed. he claimed to tame turtles,  maybe giraffes too ? b.t.w. "taming" is not the same as "domestication", e.g. you can only "tame" circus animals, they are not kept at  home, they have to be kept outside, in captivity. And bulls, as well as some pets (like e.g. cats) are very difficult to tame.

Answer (score 4):

Animals that can be domesticated are actually rather rare. I see zebras mentioned, but standard Earth zebras specifically are [one that cannot](https://www.sciencealert.com/this-is-why-zebras-have-never-been-domesticated) (cute pictures aside), largely due to dispositional reasons.

> But to survive in an environment where there is an abundance of large
> predators including lions, cheetahs and hyenas, the zebra evolved into
> a particularly alert, responsive animal that flees in the face of
> danger but also possesses a powerful response if captured.

The article goes on to talk a bit about what's required for domestication, and what happened when it was tried with zebras.

> According to the English explorer and polymath Francis Galton (a
> relative of Charles Darwin), these requirements include displaying a
> desire for comfort, being easy to tend, being useful and showing a
> fondness for man.
>
> Galton uses the zebra as an example of an unmanageable species,
> stating that the Dutch Boers repeatedly tried to break zebra to
> harness. Although they had some success, the wild, mulish nature of
> the animals would frequently break out and thwart their efforts.
>
> Although it appears possible to tame individual zebra, this species
> was not a good candidate for domestication.

Other useful traits I've seen postulated are that it has a natural social hirearchy that humans can insert themselves at the head of, and/or being a herding animal. It also needs a mating process that works within the confines of domestication. Cheetahs apparently are quite tameable, but fail on this one step because their mating process involves a several mile long chase.

Some of this is actually determinable through archeological finds, but alas rather a lot of it isn't. So there's really no way to know what species that went extinct in prehistory may have been suitable for domestication.

Further we have at least *some* indirect evidence that some of them weren't suitable for domestication, in that there's evidence South Americans were hunting and killing them, while at the same time they were also domesticating all the species in the area that *were* domesticatable (Moscovy Duck, Llama, Alpaca, Guinea Pig). This includes Toxodon and Megatherium, both of which have been found with remains butchered by humans. Native peoples know their local flora and fauna far better than we can, and if they don't think a species is domesticable, it probably isn't.

Comment: These Science Alert conditions were written by dog people ! *"requirements include (..) being useful and a fondness for man."* I don't think my cat meets these requirements.

Comment: Cats are incredibly useful. My previous cat exterminated basically every rat in a 100 yard radius of the house, sadly he died of cancer. My new cat keeps me sane and exercised as she plays chase like a dog.

Comment: @Goodies - Mine certainly has a fondness for people. TBF, that's specifically what I look for when I pick a cat from the shelter. However, you're probably not wrong that Mr. Galton, a Victorian English gentleman, while being perhaps the first word on the topic, is not the last.

Comment: @Goodies Cats, in *general*, have a fondness for man, or wouldn't have moved into his settlements to eat mice and other vermin. Not necessarily a personable fondness in every case, but at the minimum, a tolerance for living around them. (My cat however is extremely fond of me and will follow me from room to room like a puppy..)

Comment: Dunno about mice, I didn't notice. My cat is 22/24 outdoors. My cat likes the food I provide. He thanks me for it. Until the next round of food.. Cats appreciate their freedom, mine is always out. It's neither useful, nor loving. Cats are lovable.. look nice, move nice.. people love cats, I love my cat.. it's not the other way around.

Comment: @Goodies - That's not you having a pet cat. That's a 3lb neighborhood [small animal killing machine](https://www.npr.org/2020/04/18/820953617/the-killer-at-home-house-cats-have-more-impact-on-local-wildlife-than-wild-preda) that occasionally comes to you for the purposes of food security.

Comment: @T.E.D. he used to, birds too. Never takes anything home, though.. roams around, pretending to be the boss. It's a territory. I think cats remain much closer to nature than dogs. Requiring domesticated animals to love us ? It's the other way around ! We *love* piggies, we loved that first little wolf that came near for food. The animal did not get "domesticated" because it loves us. It was because we provided food. Nowadays maybe the only animals that *love us* are horses and dogs ? The rest tolerates our presence, or we keep it in captivity.. sorry about my sarcasm.

Comment: @Goodies - "Used to" likely because he killed them all. The area is now an ecological desert. [You should not let pet cats outside](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-04-02/how-bad-is-it-to-let-your-cat-outside), except in certain special circumstances (eg: barn cats).

Comment: @T.E.D. I appreciate your ethics advice, but  can't keep my cat inside a closed house, because my house is ground floor. It can go anywhere. It has done that for 15 years or so, Anyway... this is not what our chat and your answer is about. I did not downvote it, but that citation you put made me think.. this source (*not* you !) proposed animals can only be domesticated when they are *fond of humans*. I think that is projection. Animals domesticate when we want them to. When you pick up a cat from a shelter, it behaves very loving, because it prefers to go elsewhere, not be in captivity.

Comment: @Goodies - I'd say his framing is yes. Today we'd more negatively say that it has to be able to *tolerate* the presence of humans. "Affection" in his case was defined as not doing its damnedest to bite out the human's jugular, kick his head off his shoulders, or run away at high speed. I also find his framing of "comfort" a bit suspect, likely saying as much about himself as it does about domestication.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Domesticated animals, first they probably learn is *not be afraid* of us.  (+1, let's close this, else we'd get moved out to chat)